# Take the first letters of a string splitted by white space

Tags: javascript, string, split

I have a string like this:
`DEBIT CARD`. How can I extract the first letters of this string which is splitted by white space? To be more specific, I want the `D` and `C` parts of this string.

Comment: You could use a regex replace: `var str = "DEBIT CARD"; str.replace(/(\w)\w+ ?/g, '$1')`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `charAt(0)` along with `split()`:

**split(/\s+/)** will split the string into array structure based on whitespaces(single or multiple) so that you can loop over the elements of the array using **map()** and get the first character for each element. Then, finally you need to **join('')** the array and get the `string` representation.

```js
var str = 'DEBIT CARD';
var res = str.split(/\s+/).map(x=>x.charAt(0)).join('');
console.log(res);
```

Comment: You could also replace the `split` argument with a whitespace-matching regex like `/\s+/`, so that it would still work well for tabs or multiple spaces separating words.

Comment: @AaronChristiansen nice suggestion. Accepted that

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off topic / bad questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572) This question is a pretty obvious duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var stringg = 'DEBIT CARD';
var out = stringg.split(' ');
var required = out[1][0]; /* it will return only `C`, if you want the 
    first character of all letters just loop on `out` and get 0 index, 
    Here you can also use each loop or map and join functions to 
    achieve desired  output.*/
console.log(required);
```